# JavaFX can't add files from c drive

Tags: java, javafx

Hello everyone I can't add stylesheet to my JavaFX application from c drive.

I get the following error :
WARNING: Resource "file:///c:\Program Files\TSudio Edix 1X\Style.css" not found.

Here's my code:

```
Main.addExternalStyleSheet("c:\\Program Files\\TSudio Edix 1X\\Style.css");
```

And here's where I'm try to add the stylesheet:

```
public static void addExternalStyleSheet(String filelocation) {
    File f = new File(filelocation);
    scene.getStylesheets().clear();
    scene.getStylesheets().add("file:///" + f.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Any idea's of how to get it to work.

Oh and my file's location is : C:\Program Files\TSudio Edix 1X\Style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many characters which are legal in file names are not legal in a URL.  For instance, a URL uses only slashes ("/") to separate directories, regardless of the current platform;  backslashes ("") are not legal characters.  Also, spaces are not legal characters.  And everything outside the ASCII range must be UTF-8 encoded and then percent-escaped.

So, simply putting `file://` in front of a file path will not create a valid URL.

The correct way to get a URL from a file name is:

```
Paths.get(filelocation).toUri().toString()
```

More information can be found in the [documentation for the URI class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) and [RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396).  (Every URL is a URI, though URIs include more than just URLs.)